# How to make the local network test program use the network card without loopback?

Tags: tcp, localhost

I has two programs:
1.Program1: listen 0.0.0.0:22334
2.Program2: connect 192.168.10.24:22334

192.168.10.24 is local ip, the two program run in the same one server(centos7), buf the connection is being dump on the loopback interface. I already know that it is caused by local table. Is there any way to achieve this?